# '<all_urls>' is not a recognized permission

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I request a permission by this code:

```
chrome.permissions.request({permissions:["<all_urls>"]},function(granted){
        if(granted) {
            ;;
        }
    });
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running permissions.request: '<all_urls>' is not a recognized permission.
```

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<all_urls>` is an origin permission. You have to request the optional permission using [`"origins"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions#property-Permissions-origins) instead of [`"permissions"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions#property-Permissions-permissions):

```
chrome.permissions.request({origins: ["<all_urls>"] }, function(granted) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: OP needs to update his manifest as well to include optional permissions. I guess OP has not done it already.

Comment: @blunderboy If the OP did not list the permission at `"optional_permissions"`, then they would see the following unambiguous error in `chrome.runtime.lastError`: "Optional permissions must be listed in extension manifest."